# extract txt data to cloumn using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, txt

how to convert this txt into a data frame so that i can put in a column using python :

**This is the txt**

```
  Internet address is 10.210.130.10/30
  Internet address is 172.16.1.202/24
  Internet address is 151.151.151.151/32
  Internet address is 10.26.95.33/27
  Internet address is 10.26.93.1/26
  Internet address is 10.26.93.65/26
  Internet address is 10.63.121.251/28
  Internet address is 10.50.50.54/24
  Internet address is 10.26.95.22/29
  Internet address is 10.26.92.1/24
  Internet address is 10.26.81.1/24
  Internet address is 10.26.82.1/24
  Internet address is 10.26.83.1/24
  Internet address is 10.26.80.1/24
```

and I want it to be addresses numbers only to be save in a data frame so that I can create a column name "internet address" and contains the number (what is after 'is')

**Expected output as one column :**

```
Internet address 
10.210.130.10/30
172.16.1.202/24
151.151.151.151/32
10.26.95.33/27
10.26.93.1/26
```

Answer (score 1):

[`pd.read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html#pandas-read-table) can be used like so:

```
df = pd.read_table('data.txt',
                   delim_whitespace=True,
                   header=None,
                   usecols=[3],
                   names=['internet addresses'])
```

`df`:

```
    internet addresses
0     10.210.130.10/30
1      172.16.1.202/24
2   151.151.151.151/32
3       10.26.95.33/27
4        10.26.93.1/26
5       10.26.93.65/26
6     10.63.121.251/28
7       10.50.50.54/24
8       10.26.95.22/29
9        10.26.92.1/24
10       10.26.81.1/24
11       10.26.82.1/24
12       10.26.83.1/24
13       10.26.80.1/24
```

`data.txt`:

```
Internet address is 10.210.130.10/30
Internet address is 172.16.1.202/24
Internet address is 151.151.151.151/32
Internet address is 10.26.95.33/27
Internet address is 10.26.93.1/26
Internet address is 10.26.93.65/26
Internet address is 10.63.121.251/28
Internet address is 10.50.50.54/24
Internet address is 10.26.95.22/29
Internet address is 10.26.92.1/24
Internet address is 10.26.81.1/24
Internet address is 10.26.82.1/24
Internet address is 10.26.83.1/24
Internet address is 10.26.80.1/24
```